# Set inherit Zoom(action property) to bookmark in the pdf file

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have found the number of bookmarks in the pdf file using the following code.

```
var reader = new PdfReader(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\zoom.pdf", new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(""));
IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
foreach (Dictionary<string, object> bk in bookmarks)
{
    string bjj = bk.Values.ToArray().GetValue(0).ToString();
}
```

But i need to set the inherit zoom action property for book bookmark in the pdf file.

please advise me to do from above code or any other sample code in C#

Comment: Hi Bruno, Does my question is clear now? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a variation on the following questions by the same OP:

- [C# - Set inherit zoom action for all the bookmarks in the PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059100/c-sharp-set-inherit-zoom-action-for-all-the-bookmarks-in-the-pdf-file) (June 5)
- [How to set zoom level to pdf using iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087786/how-to-set-zoom-level-to-pdf-using-itextsharp-5-5-0-0) (June 6)

The previous versions of this were very unclear. Based on the comments on the previous questions, the OP wants to take the Outline tree using the `SimpleBookmark` class, change the Destinations similar to the way he changed the destinations of annotations (as shown in [C# - Set inherit zoom action for all the bookmarks in the PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059100/c-sharp-set-inherit-zoom-action-for-all-the-bookmarks-in-the-pdf-file)) and then persist these changes.

When using `SimpleBookmark`, you get the outlines in a form that is similar to [this XML-file](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/outline_tree.xml):

```
<Bookmark>
    <Title Action="GoTo" Style="bold" Page="1 FitH 572">Akira</Title>
<Bookmark>
```

You can change this XML file (or in the case of the OP the contents of the `Dictionary<string, object>` obtained from `SimpleBookmark`), for instance, you could change `1 Fith 572` into `1 Fith 580`. This is outside the scope of iText: it's a matter of changing XML or changing Strings in a Dictionary.

Once you've made the change, you need to persist the change in the PDF. For instance, you have a `bookmarks` object:

```
List<Dictionary<String, Object>> bookmarks;
```

and all the changes are reflected in this `bookmarks` object.

Now you can use `PdfStamper`'s [`setOutline()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html#setOutlines%28java.util.List%29) method (Java) to change the outlines of the document. In C#, it would be something like this:

```
stamper.Outlines = bookmarks;
```

This is only one way to approach it. Obviously, it's also possible to walk through the outline objects and change the destinations at the lowest PDF level.

If you want an example, see the [ChangeBookmarks](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/ChangeBookmarks) sample:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader);
    changeList(list);
    stamper.setOutlines(list);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}

public void changeList(List<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
    for (HashMap<String, Object> entry : list) {
        for (String key : entry.keySet()) {
            if ("Kids".equals(key)) {
                Object o = entry.get(key);
                changeList((List<HashMap<String, Object>>)o);
            }
            else if ("Page".equals(key)) {
                String dest = (String)entry.get(key);
                entry.put("Page", dest.replaceAll("Fit", "FitV 60"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As already explained, you get all the bookmarks as a `List<HashMap<String, Object>>`. You write a recursive method that goes through the outline tree (`"Kids"`) and changes all the values of the `Page` entry. In my case, the bookmarks in [bookmarks.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/bookmarks.pdf) are all of type "Fit". I replace "Fit" with "FitV 60". Take a look at [changed_bookmarks.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/changed_bookmarks.pdf) to see the difference:

[image]

Suppose that you want an XYZ destination where you inherit the zoom factor, you can take do something that is similar to what you did in a previous question you posted: [How to set zoom level to pdf using iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087786/how-to-set-zoom-level-to-pdf-using-itextsharp-5-5-0-0)

Instead of replacing "Fit" with "FitV 60", you can replace "Fit" by "XYZ 30 100 0". In this case, 30 and 100 are X,Y coordinates. The third number is the zoom level, but if you choose 0, you get "Inherit zoom".

Comment: Hi, i can't post full code, its says too long how can i show it? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you post the full code? I just gave you the answer to your question!

Comment: Sorry to ask you. i can able to get values from bookmarks object but i don't how to set the value for bookmarks object.kindly help me.Thanks.

Comment: I'm a Java developer and you're asking me how to change the value in a C# Dictionary or Array? That's... very strange. It feels as if you're pulling my leg.

Comment: Sorry bruno. I will try and get back to you if i get any error.

Comment: I have written a Proof of Concept (POC) in Java. If you're a C# developer, you shouldn't have any problem to convert it to .NET. Note that the code of this POC fits perfectly in an answer. If you have a problem, **NEVER** paste your complete code, **ALWAYS** create a small POC that demonstrates the problem, aka a SSCCE (see http://sscce.org )

Comment: i have converted your java code to C# and compile successfully but while running i did not get Fit to FitV 60(Right Click bookmark->Properties->Action Tab->Zoom Level - No change.I checked your pdf file(changed_bookmarks.pdf) that also no change in Zoom Level.If anything wrong just correct me.Thanks.

Comment: I've attached a screen shot that shows that the `/Dest` array was changed as expected.

Comment: Hi Bruno, Can i get like this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754774/itext-change-bookmarks-zoom-level-to-inherit-zoom-in-existing-pdf]. Thanks.

Comment: I'll update my answer and I'll add an answer to the question you're referring to.

Comment: Hi Bruno, as per butani vijay said , your code is not working for me. its still custom or actual size(zoom level).If you want see my code i will psot it. Thanks.

Comment: I want to see your PDF.

Comment: How can i attach a file?since i am new to this

Comment: I solved the problem. made some changes in the code. used dest = "1 XYZ 30 100 0.0"; entry["Page"]=dest; instead of entry["Page"] = dest.Replace("FitR", "XYZ 30 100 0"); now inherit zoom set for all the bookmarks.

Comment: OK, now all you have to do, is to accept the answer. That is: if you want people to keep answering questions.

Comment: By the way: your *solution* is wrong. You now have an entry with way too many parameters. You should do this. `entry["Page"] = "XYZ 30 100 0"`. If you replace `FitR` then you have the X Y Zoom parameters you add *as well as* the original parameters that were present after `FitR`.

Comment: Hello mail2vguna. if i use like entry.put("Page", dest.replaceAll("FitR", "XYZ 30 100 0"));. it set inherit zoom but when i click on bookmark unable to reach at desired location.

Comment: That's because 30 100 represent a coordinate of a location that is *chosen arbitrarily*. The values you need, will depend on the page size. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: What are replacement value for 30 and 100, its depend on page size mean shall i give the page size value?Thanks.

Comment: I am using following code to reach at desired location in the bookmark. replace dest = "1 XYZ 30 100 0.0"; using dest = "1 XYZ 0 792 0.0";

Comment: First you can read bookmark...parse x and y if present and use it... i have solved this problem with the help of Bruno

Comment: Hi Vijay, I agreed. How can i get X and Y value from PDF? help me.Thanks.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I am getting value 1 XYZ -28 795 1.0 then my value for setting inherit zoom is dest="XYZ -28 1.0 0.0" am i correct or wrong? Thanks.

Comment: No, the value should be XYZ -28 795 0 (you were changing the Y coordinate and the Z-factor; you only need to change the Z-factor).

Comment: Thanks bruno. i will check and get back to you.

Comment: Bruno, One of the pdf file, i am getting dest = "2 Fit" from dest = (string)entry[key]; in this case how can i set the value for inherit zoom. Thanks.

Comment: Fit doesn't require parameters. It just makes sure the page fits the viewer window. Use your common sense to find an X and Y value and change the Fit into XYZ with three values (of which the Z-factor is 0).