# Read and change zoom level of named destinations in pdf

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I'd like to read and change zoom level of named destinations in a pdf file using `iText 7`. Ive come up with the following code:

```
Map<String, PdfObject> names =
                    document.getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.Dests).getNames();

for (Map.Entry<String, PdfObject> dest : names.entrySet()) {
    if (dest.getValue().isArray()) {
        PdfArray arr = (PdfArray) dest.getValue();
        PdfName asName = arr.getAsName(1); //  /Fit
        arr.set(1, FitR);
        //System.out.println();
        arr.setModified();
    }
}
```

However, this code fails to work against my example file and has other flaws as well.
Most importantly, it tries to deal with one type of zoom (`/Fit`), but other types (`/XYZ` and so on) should also be handled with. Second, I don't know how to get the page number of named destination as key pair `named of destination` and its `zoom value` doesn't seem to have this information. Please see a screenshot of debug session below:

[image]

**Note**, at SO there is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975088/changing-the-zoom-level-for-named-destinations-on-a-pdf-file?rq=1) dealing with exactly the same topic. The thing is the answer to that question give too little information to deal with this problem.